# How to read an 8 bit image file?

Tags: c#, image

I am currently working on an image reading and soring project. And I wanted to ask how can I read an 8-bit image file? If it helps I have a working code that can read a 24-bit image file. The code reads the image color codes and adds them to an array. I want to do something like that with an 8-bit image file.

```
var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path);        

image.Save(name + "_24bit.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(name + "_24bit.bmp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] b = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(b, 0, (int)file.Length);
    int width = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0x00012);
    int height = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0x0016);
    int points = (width * height);


    //Taškus verčiame į spalvų kodus
    int[] bs = new int[points];
    int j = 54;
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.Length; i++)
    {
        bs[i] = (((b[j + 2] << 8) + b[j + 1]) << 8) + b[j];
        j += 3;
    }
    //
}
```

Comment: An 8bpp image always has a color table.  Don't use a file, use Bitmap.LockBits() instead.

Comment: Weird code... why are you writing and then reading a bitmap file, rather than using system functions like `LockBits` to get the image contents directly from the Bitmap object?

Comment: This all seems like [an XY problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) to me. What are you _really_ trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score -1):

An 8 bit image file has each pixel represented by just 1 byte, rather than 3 as per 24 bit.

You'll need to determine if its 8-bit colour or 8-bit greyscale.

8-bit colour is packed as RRRGGGBB e.g. 3 bits for Red, 3 for Green and 2 for Blue.
A grey-scale image just shows the amount of luminance of the pixel.

In fact a 24-bit colour image can be thought of 3 channels of 8-bit greyscale one assigned to each colour (Red, Green, Blue).

Comment: I've modified the code slightly based on your feedback.

Comment: `byte[] b = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(b, 0, (int)file.Length);
                int width = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0x00012);
                int height = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0x0016);
                int points = (width * height);
                
                int[] bs = new int[points];
                int j = 54;
                for (int i = 0; i < bs.Length; i++)
                {
                    //bs[i] = (((b[j + 2] << 8) + b[j + 1]) << 8) + b[j];
                    bs[i] = b[j];
                    j += 1;
                }`

Comment: 8-bit images can also use indexed color with a 24-bit palette. That's more common than 8-bit RRRGGGBB format

Comment: @phuclv There is no such thing as 8-bit RGB in the same sense as 16-bit RGB. 8-bit is _always_ indexed.

Comment: @Nyerguds who said that you can't have [8-bit RGB color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color#Color_quantization)? There are [**real** 8-bit RGB formats in **real** devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_palettes#3-3-2_bit_RGB).  It's just not common because it's much more useless than 8-bit index color

Comment: Technically, sure, but it's still completely irrelevant here, since this is a question using `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. And `System.Drawing` supports no such format. Anything that's 8 bit or lower is considered indexed. Which, unlike what this answer says, does **not** equal grayscale. Talking about 2 and 3 bit colour components here will only unnecessarily confuse OP.